# PyDeV Predefined Module Not recognized beyond 2 -level package structure

Tags: python, eclipse-rcp, pydev

I'm programmatically adding predefined modules to my interpreter in PyDev. It works for a module with a single level package structure, but not for one with two levels.

This works

```
AAA\
  |---__init__.py
  |
AAA.xx.pypredef
```

from AAA import xx #code completion for AAA.xx.pypredef works

This does not work

```
AAA\
  |----__init__.py
  |
  |----BBB\
  |      |
  |      |---__init__.py
  |
AAA.BBB.xx.pypredef
```

from AAA.BBB import xx #code completion for AAA.BBB.xx.pypredef does not work

I also tried

```
AAA\
  |----__init__.py
  |
  |---BBB\
        |---__init__.py
  |
  |BBB.xx.pypredef
```

and

```
AAA\
  |----__init__.py
  |
  |---BBB\
        |---__init__.py
        |xx.pypredef
```

In all cases from AAA.BBB import xx code completion does not work

WWhat is the proper structure needed to enable me to provide code completion for module AA.BB.xx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just checked it here and the structure:

```
AAA\

  |----__init__.py
  |
  |----BBB\
  |      |
  |      |---__init__.py
  |
AAA.xx.pypredef 
AAA.BBB.xx.pypredef
```

does work for me (given that the parent folder of AAA, AAA.xx.pypredef and AAA.BBB.xx.pypredef is added to the predefined completions at pydev > interpreters > python interpreter > select interpreter > predefined).

One thing to note is that the information won't be updated if you just change the .pypredef files... you have to go to the interpreters preferences page (pydev > interpreters > python interpreter), press 'apply' and select which interpreters should be restored (at that point it'll reparse the .pypredef files).

Comment: Thanks for replying, Fabio. I discovered that the problem wasn't in the structure, but the way I was doing the import.

I was doing: <import AAA>
And code completion was not working on <AAA.BBB.xx> (but the functions in xx are called successfully when the program runs.

When I did: <from AAA.BBB import xx>
then the code completion on xx works, and it executes successfully.

Is this expected behavior? Is the syntax for importing modules more restrictive for predefs than for python in general?

Comment: However, when I have the structure <AAA.xx> instead of <AAA.BBB.xx>, then I can use <import AAA> and code completion works for AAA.xx.

I have two modules with the same signature. One of them is in AAA, and the other is in AAA.BBB. So I'm trying to add a predef for each of them, but the one with a nested package only works with the import syntax I mentioned above.

Comment: Actually, this is expected even for Python: you have to import the whole module to access it (some modules such as 'os.path' don't need that because 'os' puts 'path' as an attribute, but in general, if you don't import the full module name, it won't be accessible even in regular python -- pypredef files should work the same way).

Comment: OK thanks. Sorry, I'm fairly new to python. I wonder why it seemed to work for me with a partial import. I just want to make sure the code completion doesn't have more restrictive requirements than python itself, so thanks for setting me straight on that.

Comment: On further reflection, it seems desirable for PyDev to support partial imports. My code works with partial imports because the submodules are imported within the parent module. So I have to restrict the user's usage of import if they want custom code completion. I created a feature request for this at https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/ (inbox item 647).

Comment: Per Fabio's instructions on the PyDev ticket I opened, partial module import is supported by defining a pypredef file for each package level. So AAA.pypredef contians "from AAA import BBB", and AAA.BBB.pypredef contains "from AAA.BBB import xx". Then code completion for AAA.BBB.xx works after import AAA.